# Grid navigation problem

Tags: combinatorics

The number of paths from one point to another through a grid can be solved in two methods: either by combinations or by implying the concept of Pascal's triangle.
My question is:
Should the grid necessarily be square or rectangular? If the grid is triangular, and one wants to go from one point to another, can the number of paths be counted? 
And I also want to ask, what will be the solution in case of a 3d grid?
This is where I am getting stuck. If someone helps me with the problems, I'll be obliged.

Comment: What do you mean by _path_ exactly? (The details are crucial. With [the classic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)), you dive into a fairly difficult field - see e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.7216.pdf); but your note on rectangular grids makes me suspect that you might mean [walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#walk) - with _much_ simpler handling - or something else).

Comment: (This includes the question what are the _graphs_ you consider - i.e. what are (allowed) edges/arcs of.)

Comment: Yes Sir... I mean Walks

Comment: Sir...in case of 3d grids?

Comment: For _directed_ $m_1\times\ldots\times m_n$ grid (with arcs increasing each single coordinate by $1$), the number of walks from $(0, \ldots, 0)$ to $(m_1, \ldots, m_n)$ is $\frac{(m_1+\ldots+m_n)!}{m_1!\cdot\ldots\cdot m_n!}$. For "triangular grid" you still need to specify what its arcs/edges are. See my answer for some general cases.

Answer (score 1):

For counting *walks*, the situation is fairly simple.

First, for any finite *graph* (directed or not, or even a multigraph) $G$ with [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $A$, and a natural number $n$, the matrix $A^n$ [counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers) walks of length exactly $n$ - namely, its entry at $(u,v)$ (where $u$ and $v$ are vertices of $G$, and we "number" rows and columns of the matrices with vertices) is equal to the number $W_{u,v}^G(n)$ of walks of length $n$ from $u$ to $v$, and if we now consider the "exponential generating function" (EGF)
$$F_{u,v}^G(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{W_{u,v}^G(n)}{n!}t^n,$$
the matrix formed by all these functions is [$e^{tA}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Next, *rectangular grids* are special cases of [cartesian products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of graphs (in particular, 3D grid is a product of three simple path graphs). Let $G_1, G_2$ be graphs. A walk of length $n_1$ from $u_1$ to $v_1$ in $G_1$, together with a walk of length $n_2$ from $u_2$ to $v_2$ in $G_2$, give rise to $\binom{n_1 + n_2}{n_1} = \frac{(n_1 + n_2)!}{n_1! n_2!}$ walks of length $n_1 + n_2$ from $(u_1, u_2)$ to $(v_1, v_2)$ in the cartesian product $G_1\ \Box\ G_2$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$. From this it is easy to conclude that
$$F_{(u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2)}^{G_1\ \Box\ G_2}(t) = F_{u_1,v_1}^{G_1}(t) F_{u_2,v_2}^{G_2}(t).$$
Thus, the EGF counting walks in cartesian product of two (or more!) graphs is simply the product of EGFs for each of the graphs. In terms of matrices, this corresponds to [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

In particular, this allows you to get the EGF for 3D rectangular grids if you compute it for 1D paths. In the undirected case, the latter requires you to compute $e^{tA}$ for [tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) matrix $A$ of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & & & & & \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & & & & \\ & 1 & 0 & 1 & & & \\ & & 1 & 0 & 1 & & \\ & & & 1 & 0 & 1 & \\ & & & & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ & & & & & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
(In the directed case this is **trivial** - at most a single walk is possible - and gives well-known results for, say, 2D grid with "up" and "right" movements possible, and similarly for greater dimensions.)

The rest depends on the form of computation results you need (a general formula for a given graph, or the first few values, or whatever else).