# Modified "Grid Path" question

Tags: combinatorics

We all know a result of "How many ways can you move from (0, 0) to (m, n) moving only positive x and y unit moves". It is $\binom{n+m}{n}$, also shown as following:

$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \ldots \\ 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & \ldots \\ 1 & 4 & 10 & 20 & 35 & \ldots \\ 1 & 5 & 15 & 35 & 70 & \ldots \end{matrix}$$

I will denote this as $S = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$, as you can move from $(x, y)$ to $(x + s_0, y + s_1) \forall s \in S$. Also denote the ways of moving from (0, 0) to (m, n) as $f(S) = \binom{n+m}{n}$.

**Question: Is there a similar formula for**
$$S = \{(x, 0) \forall x \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}\} \cup \{(0, y) \forall y \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}\} = $$

$$\{(0, 1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),\cdots,(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),\cdots\}$$?

This "Move set" basically means you can move "like a rook", with any distance but only right and downward.

P.S. I have developed this notation as I am planning to have a few more questions like this. Is there an actual formal notation for this?

P.P.S. For programmers, this problem can be solved with Dynamic Programming.

[Try it yourself](https://repl.it/@GarethMa/BoldEasygoingInversion)

Comment: nice question!  but the movements you're describing is "like a rook".  a queen would also be able to move diagonally i.e. $(1,1), (2,2), ...$

Comment: Following [these lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979384/grid-navigation-problem/2979728), the number of ways from $(0,0)$ to $(n_1,n_2)$ should be $$\sum_{d_1=1}^{n_1}\sum_{d_2=1}^{n_2}\binom{d_1+d_2}{d_1}\binom{n_1-1}{d_1-1}\binom{n_2-1}{d_2-1},$$ but I don't see further simplifications.